# How to save multiple values from dropdown with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to save multiple store ids in Test table in store_id column. What is the best way to design model to save multiple store ids in Test table

After updating the model. I am seeing Error-"Enter a list values". In my database store_id is int datatype. should it be CHAR datatype?
models.py

```
class Store(models.Model):
      store_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="store")
      
      def __str__(self):
         return self.name
class Test(models.Model):
      store_id =models.ManyToManyField(Store,db_column='store_id')
      def __str__(self):
         return self.store_id
```

Forms.py

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['store_id'] = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Store.objects.all(), widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'multiple':'multiple'})
      class Meta:
           model = Test
           fields = ('store_id',)
```

Views.py

```
def store_create(request, slog_id=None):
    slog =(get_object_or_404(Test, id=slog_id) if slog_id else None)
    if request.method == "POST":
       formset = TestForm(request.POST)
       stores = request.POST.getlist('store_id')
       updated_data = request.POST.copy()
       store_list = []
       for i in stores:
          new_list = Store.objects.get(id=int(i))
          store_list.append(new_list.id)
       updated_data.update({'store_id':store_list})
       if formset.is_valid():
          formset.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to save multiple store ids in Test table in store_id column.

You can't. This is a field that essentially mimics the column of the primary key of a `Store`, so it can contain only one such value.

A [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), this will create a [*junction table* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) in between that wil link to a `Store` and a `Test`, so:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='store')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Test(models.Model):
    stores = models.ManyToManyField(Store)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}'
```

In the form, this will work with a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield):

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['stores'].widget.attrs.update(class='form-control')
      class Meta:
           model = Test
           fields = ('stores',)
```

as for the view, just let the form handle it properly:

```
def store_create(request, slog_id=None):
    slog = Test.objects.first(id=slog_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=slog)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `…_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `store`, instead of <s>`store_id`</s>.

Answer (score 0):

To save multiple store IDs in the `Test` table from a dropdown you need to switch your `store_id` field in the `Test` model to use a `ManyToManyField` instead of a `ForeignKey`.

Update your `models.py` like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Store(models.Model):
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="store")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.store_name

class Test(models.Model):
    store_id = models.ManyToManyField(Store)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Test {self.id}'
```

Then update your `forms.py` with this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, ModelMultipleChoiceField, SelectMultiple
from .models import Test, Store

class TestForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['store_id'] = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=Store.objects.all(), 
            widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('store_id',)
```

You used both `__str__` and `__unicode__` methods in your models which is not necessary, in Python 3 and Django versions supporting Python 3, you should only define the `__str__` method for your models. The `__unicode__` method was used in Python 2 to ensure that the representation of `non-ASCII` characters is handled correctly. Since Python 3 uses Unicode by default for strings, `__unicode__` is no longer necessary.

Comment: I am seeing error- "Enter a List of values" while saving the form with multiple options from dropdown. In my database, store_id is int datatype. Should the datatype is CHAR in database for store_id?                stores = request.POST.getlist('store_id')
       updated_data = request.POST.copy()
       store_list = []
       for i in stores:
          new_list = Store.objects.get(id=int(i))
          store_list.append(new_list.id)
       updated_data.update({'store_id':store_list})
       if formset.is_valid():
          formset.save()

Comment: @Hadoopek how you are using the `TestForm` logic in your views? Can you please add that code block?